# In this PYTHON program, why is 5 the correct answer to all?

Tags: python

When I run the below quiz game that I made in python, when I give the answer as 5, it says correct for all.

See the image given
[image: Wrong answer show as correct!!]

I could not understand why.

Comment: For every question, the `match` statement checks all the `case` terms until it finds one that matches. The problem is that you haven't told your program anything about which answer belongs to which question. You could consider using a dictionary to map each question to its correct answer.

Comment: Also, any correct answer will be considered correct for any question.  Change your case "5" to case "15" and 15 will be correct for any answer.  BTW: there are not 26 alphabets in the English language, there are 26 letters in the English alphabet.

Comment: Thanks man!! Now, I understood the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been said in the comments, "match" checks every case until it finds a match.
You will need to associate an answer with each question individually.

You could make a list of answers and use the index to print the correct question and check if the input is the correct answer.